# Cauchy's integral formula for Cayley-Hamilton Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, functional-calculus, cayley-hamilton

I'm just working through Conway's book on complex analysis and I stumbled across this lovely exercise:

> Use Cauchy's Integral Formula to prove the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem: If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix over $\mathbb C$ and $f(z)  = \det(z-A)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ then $f(A) = 0$. (This exercise was taken from a paper by C. A. McCarthy, *Amer. Math. Monthly*, **82** (1975), 390-391)

Unfortunately, I was not able to find said paper. I'm completely lost with this exercise. I can't even start to imagine how one could possibly make use of Cauchy here...

Thanks for any hints.

Regards, S.L.

Comment: A brief google search gave [this note](http://leandromat.files.wordpress.com/2009/11/cauchycaley1.pdf).

Comment: See the "quatrième méthode" in [Marc Sage, *Théorème de Cayley-Hamilton : quatre démonstrations*](https://www.normalesup.org/~sage/Enseignement/Cours/CaylHami.pdf).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The idea is to use [holomorphic functional calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus) and to show that for a matrix $A$ and a polynomial $p(z)$ we have for $r \gt \|A\|$ 
\begin{equation}\tag{$\ast$}
p(A) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z| = r} p(z) \cdot (z - A)^{-1}\ \,dz
\end{equation}
in complete analogy with the Cauchy formula for complex numbers. The integral of a matrix of holomorphic functions is defined by integrating each entry separately.

By [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), the $(k,l)$-entry of $(z-A)^{-1}$ is $\displaystyle ((z-A)^{-1})_{k,l} = \frac{1}{\det(z-A)} c_{k,l}(z)$ where $c_{k,l}(z)$ is some polynomial in $z$. Let $p(z) = \det(z-A)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Conclude using $(\ast)$ by applying [Cauchy's integral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_integral_theorem) to $c_{k,l}$.

---

To see that the identity $(\ast)$ holds, proceed as follows (this is a slight variant of McCarthy's argument):

- The [usual matrix norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) induced by the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ satisfies $\|A^{n}\| \leq \|A\|^{n}$.
- Use this to show that $(z - A)^{-1} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{A^{n}}{z^{n+1}}$, where the right hand side converges uniformly on $\{|z| \gt \|A\| + \varepsilon\}$.
- It follows that we can interchange integration and summation. Conclude that $$ A^{k} = \int_{|z| = r} z^{k} (z - A)^{-1}\,dz$$ and $(\ast)$ follows by linearity.

---

Here's a [link to McCarthy's article](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2318415) (you need a university subscription to download it, but the first page is almost the entire article).

Comment: Ah, that's great. Thanks a lot, Theo!

Comment: What a beatiful proof. :)

Comment: @S. L.: I like it too, and I didn't know it before. Thanks for asking this question!

Comment: Beautiful indeed! Since I can't give one more upvote than I would've loved to give, let me mention instead what is (methinks) an apropos paper: *[The Equivalence of Definitions of a Matric Function](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2306996)* by Rinehart (p. 399, in particular). This Cauchy construction has been [used numerically](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/729/NA-07-17.pdf) as well.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks a lot for these links! Good to see you're back in town, at least occasionally :)